# Can the goverment force me to decrypt a hard-drive in Norway?

Tags: search-and-seizure, norway

I have very little knowledge about the Norwegian laws and the cryptography parts of it.

Suppose the police seize my computer and all my hard-drives on suspicion that I have pirated software.  All of my drives are encrypted with BitLocker. Can they force me to provide a decryption key? What would consequences be of refusing to provide it?

Comment: Note the U.S. answer here: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1523/10

Answer (score 1):

In Norway, the government may be able to force one to decrypt a hard drive as part of a criminal investigation. The Norwegian Criminal Procedure Act allows the police to require individuals to provide assistance in the investigation, including the decryption of encrypted devices.

Refusing to provide a decryption key may result in consequences such as being held in contempt of court or being charged with obstruction of justice. It is important to seek legal counsel if one is facing such situation in Norway to fully understand one's rights and options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).